# jquery validate custom rule: if select a , b is required, vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to validate two text box

textbox a, textbox b

if a input , b is require
if b input, a is require

To be simple , all of the box is required if any one box / both have input
What should be this custom valid rule? Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.tabbable').tabs();
$("#selectList").validate({
    rules: {
   ...what rules should be add
           },
       })
    });
```

Comment: You want to validate *both* elements, or validate only under certain circumstances?

Comment: both of them , the logic is , check a /b , if at least one of them have input, then but of them are required